# Biased moderation?

Tags: discussion

In this [answer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/28801/can-anyone-find-any-redeeming-qualities-in-the-vulture/28818?noredirect=1#comment45588_28818), which is almost exactly the same answer Brian Towers already deleted, and moved to comments, because it did not answer the question, the poster re-posted it, and added nothing to it other than this derogatory paragraph:

"Addressing the unwritten question, your last three questions do display a psychological problem. I would have more respect if you posted one of your games and asked, "Don't I play great?""

When I flag this, why is this RUDE comment not dealt with, and declined as "no evidence to support it" as rude?

I have tried hard to ask and answer thoughtful questions, but you let that stand? That is not OK.

Is there an appeal process?

UPDATE: They finally deleted the abusive answer, but I am still not why it was not deleted the first time. When I brought it up in the overall Stack Exchange Meta site, while I was not supported in the way that I brought this up since they did not think that I waited long enough for resolution here, it was universally agreed that the original answer was rude.

Comment: Speaking as a mod on another site, please remember that mods are just humans. We sometimes get flags wrong, we misunderstand the situation, we misclick or fatfinger a response. Whenever you feel a flag was not handled properly, your first instinct should be to come to meta and just ask why. Don't assume malice, first ask politely what happened and why. Maybe the mods had a very good reason you're unaware of. Or maybe they made an honest mistake. Maybe they even have it in for you personally, but you can't know if you don't ask so please don't jump to conclusions.

Comment: @terdon To be honest, I am outspoken about the ways that some of things on SE are done, like about duplicate questions being closed on new users when it is really only the answer that is similar. I l also questioned when a mod deleted a conversation that he was a part of. And frankly, I have a temporary goal, and this SE has limited questions, and I have been a question hog until I get there; and I am sure not everyone appreciates that, but I still expect the same protections afforded to others. I feel at times that they won't do that. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Being outspoken and being aggressive and rude are not the same thing. All I'm saying is that I know I've fumbled a few flags in my time, either because I had misunderstood or because the interface leaves a lot to be desired and I simply misclicked. If you don't come in swinging and assuming the worst, you are far likelier to get a helpful answer. Especially since you might be wrong and there was no malice involved. As indeed seems to have been the case here.

Comment: We will have to disagree about whether it seems to be the case since there is no evidence to support either position, benign, or otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

I've deleted that answer; unless you happen to have the book, it's completely useless. It suffers from the same problems as [link only answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259).

I agree that the cited paragraph is not respectful; self-answers are [encouraged](https://chess.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). Moreover, it does not provide an answer to the question; if that user has any problems with the way you write your posts, they should take it to Meta.

Why that flag has been declined, I don't know. In the moderator dashboard, you can't see the entire answer unless you click through; perhaps the problematic paragraph wasn't shown. It's fine to write an appeal on Meta, but please be careful how you word it.

Comment: +1 Thank you for your explanation. Frankly, I was very upset at that attack, and that nothing was done, thus, my original question above was borderline, but by comparison, it was not directed at one person.